# How to make a retrofit call in Work Manager

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I want to send a news notification to my users every 15 minutes, but it does not call retrofit data in work manager.

Work Manager Create

```
val constrains = Constraints.Builder()
        .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
        .build()

    val notificationPeriodicWorks = PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(NotificationPeriodicWorks::class.java , 20  ,TimeUnit.MINUTES , 5 , TimeUnit.MINUTES)
        .setConstraints(constrains)
        .addTag("NotificationWork")
        .build()
    WorkManager.getInstance(applicationContext).enqueueUniquePeriodicWork("NotificationPeriodicWorks" , ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP , notificationPeriodicWorks)
```

doWork()

```
val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("URL")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()
val dailyNews = retrofit.create(everydayNews::class.java)
                                dailyNews.getDayNews().enqueue(object : Callback<Model1>{
                                    override fun onResponse(call: Call<Model1>,response: Response<Model1>) {
                                        val title = response.body()!!.articles[0].title
                                        println("Data $title")
                                        sendNotification(title , "News - Daily" , 1)
                                    }

                                    override fun onFailure(call: Call<Model1>, t: Throwable) {
                                        TODO("Not yet implemented")
                                    }

                                })
```

My code is in its simplest form, let's say the user wants to receive daily news every 15 minutes, but support is not working for the business manager.
how do I solve this problem or suggest a way?
(I'm using Google translate, there may be errors)

Comment: I would use foreground service for such cases

Comment: I don't know, wouldn't the constant news notification be disturbing after a while?
can be used other than that